# VertexDelete Problem

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I am doing a straightforward deletion of a set of vertices in a Tree using Mathematica.

```
     a = CompleteKaryTree[5, DirectedEdges -> True];
     b = TreePlot[a, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

The tree looks fine.

However, I want to delete some vertices:

```
     c = VertexDelete[a, {11, 12}];
     d = TreePlot[c, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Although I deleted Vertices 11 and 12, the resultant graph still contains vertices labeled 11 and 12. Is there a bug in VertexDelete?

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not a bug in `VertexDelete`.

Some background first:

`TreePlot`, along with `GraphPlot`, is an old function that predates the introduction of `Graph` objects.  Consider it deprecated that is only kept for backwards compatibility.

The proper way to display vertex labels for a `Graph` object is

```
g = CompleteKaryTree[5, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Or if you already have `g`, then you can use

```
SetProperty[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Or even use (since Mathematica 10)

```
Graph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

If `g` was originally created using `CompleteKaryTree` then this latter form will not work.  That *is* a bug, but completely unrelated to your question.

---

With the standard, modern way of displaying graphs you can observe that `VertexDelete` does give a correct result:

```
VertexDelete[g, {11, 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why does `TreePlot` appear to show this graph incorrectly then?

That's because as I said `TreePlot` was introduced in version 6 when there were no `Graph` objects.  The tree was instead specified as a list of rules.  It was not even possible to plot a forest (i.e. multiple unconnected trees, like your example) with it.  `TreePlot` is still included in the current version for the sake of backwards compatibility: so Mathematica can still run old programs *which do not use `Graph`*.

`TreePlot` was also updated to have *some* support for `Graph` objects, but this support is incomplete.  The *names* of vertices are not preserved when converting a `Graph` to a `TreePlot` compatible form.  What is displayed with `VertexLabeling -> True` is not the names of vertices in this case, but their indices.

---

**In short:**

**Do not use old deprecated graph functions with new `Graph` objects.  Use the new functionality: everything that `TreePlot` could do has a newer alternative.**

There are several [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html)s especially suitable for trees:

```
SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, {11, 12}], 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The others are `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, `"BalloonEmbedding"` and `"RadialEmbedding"`.  The root vertex can also be specified, please check [here](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cg5b79gi-1e4g1s).

The [IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) has a few additional tree-specific layouts which may give slightly different results than Mathematica's builtin.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bug. Vertices 11 and 12 were indeed deleted from `a`.

```
a = CompleteKaryTree[5, DirectedEdges -> True];
VertexList@a
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>   20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}

```
c = VertexDelete[a, {11, 12}];
VertexList@c
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
>   22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}

When you plot two trees, vertices 5 and 6 each direct to two vertices in `a` and only to one vertex in `c`. The labeling of vertices on the plot has changed but the vertices didn't.

```
TreePlot[a, VertexLabeling -> True]
TreePlot[c, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Szabolcs, Pavlo Fesenko. Thanks for your time. Your answers were very informative!